# ORB object tracking on Raspberry pi

Tags: python-3, opencv

I am new to Rasberry Pi and OpenCV

but I got a project to make a target detection tool using ORB from openCV with raspberry pi

I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and the Raspberry Pi Camera V2 8MP
and I already install OpenCV version 4.5.1-dev

is it possible to do that? and are there any good examples for this project?

Comment: this a Python question, possibly Linux ... not specific to Raspberry Pi ... do yourself a favor and stop limiting your chance of success by searching for Raspberry Pi information only

Comment: okay, im gonna ask on python community
shoul i delete this question then?

Comment: you could leave it ... I'm just saying that you need to be aware of what your question is about ... that way you can reach the widest audience that can help you